# Unable To Ping External Hosts Using In Perl Using Net::Ping

Tags: linux, perl

In Perl (5.16.3), I'm trying to use Net::Ping to test whether a remote host is available or not. I'm able to ping "internal" hosts which I know are online within my company's LAN, but I'm unable to ping "external" ones. Specifically, trying to ping 'www.google.com' fails.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Ping;

my $hostname1 = 'prophet'; #internal
my $hostname2 = 'www.google.com'; #external

my $p;
my $rv1;
my $rv2;

$p = Net::Ping->new();

$rv1 = $p->ping($hostname1);
$rv2 = $p->ping($hostname2);


print "Response1: $rv1\n";
print "Response2: $rv2\n";
```

Yields this result:

```
[oracle@prophet:bin]$ ./ping_test
Response1: 1
Response2: 0
[oracle@prophet:bin]$
```

Even though using the (CentOS) **ping** utility does show that 'www.google.com' is available:

```
[oracle@prophet:bin]$ which ping; ping www.google.com
/usr/bin/ping
PING www.google.com (64.233.177.105) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 64.233.177.105: icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=15.6 ms
64 bytes from 64.233.177.105: icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 time=15.6 ms
64 bytes from 64.233.177.105: icmp_seq=3 ttl=46 time=15.7 ms
64 bytes from 64.233.177.105: icmp_seq=4 ttl=46 time=16.5 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 15.614/15.884/16.547/0.394 ms
[oracle@prophet:bin]$
```

I realize that if I do this (in my Perl program):

```
$p = Net::Ping->new('icmp');
```

Then **su - root** before I run the program, it'll work...

```
[oracle@prophet:bin]$ su root
Password:    
[root@prophet:bin]# ./ping_test
Response1: 1
Response2: 1
[root@prophet:bin]#
```

... but, I'd like to be able to use Net::Ping (w/ icmp packets) **without** having to **su - root**. It's actually a requirement for an automation program I need to write. It seems a little crazy to me that I can run the **ping** (CentOS) utility as a regular user and get the expected results, but that trying to use Net::Ping as a regular user is a no-go.

Any ideas?

- G

Comment: The reason you can run `ping` as a non-root user is that it uses setuid root or has the CAP_NET_RAW capability set on some systems.

Answer (score 2):

The `ping` utility works because it's setuid — it runs with root privileges, even when executed by a normal user:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 44168 May  7  2014 /bin/ping
```

Like it or not, using ICMP inherently requires root privileges. You can't do it as a normal user.

If you want to check for connectivity, consider making a TCP connection. (Or, heck, a full HTTP request.)

Comment: Possible workaround: write a wrapper in C that execs the script and setuid root on the wrapper as described in [perlsec](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Security-Bugs).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, Way too complicated. Just execute the `ping` utility with the `-c` option and check the exit code.